# Does Survey Monkey Have any API to Save User Information, I want to save visitor name and email when he start the survey

Tags: surveymonkey

I want to save visitor information into survey monkey dashboard for analytics purpose. Not sure how I can do this. We get the user information from FB like user name and email, when user click on start the survey button I want to save this information. Can anyone Help on this or this is possible using surveymonkey API.

Comment: Yes , we show them popup that We will use their information , then only we proceed to do so..

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially [store them as a contact](https://developer.surveymonkey.com/api/v3/#contacts) in your contact list.

Example:

POST /v3/contacts

```
{
   "first_name": "test",
   "last_name": "example",
   "email": "test@example.com"
}
```

With contacts they are unique by email so if you try to create another contact for the same user it should overwrite the previous one. You can look more into contacts in the [help center](https://help.surveymonkey.com/articles/en_US/kb/Contacts).